# Sailsjs sometime the locally hosted logo does not load at all

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I'm running Sails V0.10.5 and

```
'get /': {
    controller: 'VenueController',
    action: 'index'
  },

  'get /:name': {
    controller: 'VenueController',
    action: 'showProfile'
  }
```

When I got to the index method the images are served perfectly, but when im at the showProfile method the image at /images/logo.png does not load sometime. This is like after 5-7 page refresh.

I do not know why this happens at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

simply, it's because you're not using absolute path to your image locations.

```
//change this
<img src="your/image/path.jpg" />
//to this
<img src="/your/image/path.jpg" />
//dont' forget the path relative to assests folder
```

ps: this is my first answer, sorry for some mistake

Comment: there is no absolute path in Sailsjs. When you lift Sailjs all the images are in .tmp folder and you have to add all your files relative assets folder    >    http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Assets?q=indexhtml     Thanks for your time

Comment: my logo is also in my assets/images folder as I do not have a CDN for my project

Comment: recently, i get this problem too mate . 
My solution works well, just try relifted sails, and try delete .tmp folders manually.

Comment: @user3839915 @port115  Hey guys, your processed assets are served from `.tmp/public/` in Sails.  So if you hit `/` (the web root URL), you're getting whatever is located at the root of `.tmp/public/`.  Hope that helps!